# AWS DMS Build tables list failed

Tags: sql-server, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I am trying to do a full load from SQL server to Aurora-mysql but the task fails on some error. 
I wonder why AWS are so cheap on description with this.

> ```
>   [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Execute Request Task 'LEDGD7DCQS4IBQSXXQF66YPLIU' running full load only with flags fresh start with cdcPosition null and stop_at null (replicationtask.c:702)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task 'LEDGD7DCQS4IBQSXXQF66YPLIU' running full load only in fresh start mode (replicationtask.c:1239)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task Id: bdef8ae7-25e8-432c-bf33-06f6fc86e673 (replicationtask.c:3008)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Creating threads for all components (replicationtask.c:1869)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Build tables list failed [1020486] (replicationtask.c:1993)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Task 'LEDGD7DCQS4IBQSXXQF66YPLIU' failed [1020486] (replicationtask.c:3038)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]W: Task 'LEDGD7DCQS4IBQSXXQF66YPLIU' encountered a fatal error (repository.c:4704)
>     [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task Management thread terminated abnormally (replicationtask.c:3645)
> ```

Why would "build tables list failed" what do I need to check... went over the documentation, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

'Resume' instead of 'Restart' made the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the default logging for the SOURCE_UNLOAD to a more granular level. Both of these are lower than the default level.

LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEBUG – Debug messages, informational messages, warnings, and error messages are written to the log.

LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG – All information is written to the log.

You will need to use the CLI to create the task and reference a custom task settings file for this.

Source: [AWS DMS Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.Logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need aditionals GRANT on the user configurated on DMS EndPoint.

```
 GRANT SELECT ON FN_DBLOG TO dmstest;
 GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO dmstest;
 use msdb;
 GRANT EXECUTE ON MSDB.DBO.SP_STOP_JOB TO dmstest;
 GRANT EXECUTE ON MSDB.DBO.SP_START_JOB TO dmstest;
 GRANT SELECT ON MSDB.DBO.BACKUPSET TO dmstest;
 GRANT SELECT ON MSDB.DBO.BACKUPMEDIAFAMILY TO dmstest;
 GRANT SELECT ON MSDB.DBO.BACKUPFILE TO dmstest;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.Security